# Google Compute Engine Keeps Making Instances

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I deployed my app earlier today and now I want to deploy an improved update to it, but I cannot because everytime I try to delete/stop the old instances new ones just spawn automatically.  I am deploying with:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote
```

How do I get it to stop creating more and more instances after I delete them?

Answer (score 0):

First option is a flag that comes with the deploy command:

```
 --stop-previous-version
        Stop the previously running version when deploying a new version that
        receives all traffic (off by default). Use --no-stop-previous-version
        to disable.

gcloud app deploy --stop-previous-version
```

Another option is to keep deploying to the same version:

```
gcloud app deploy --version=test
```

Another option is to explicitly delete your versions, either from the console, or:

```
gcloud app versions list
gcloud app versions delete <version-to-delete>
```

Comment: I assume @Bill Prin was using some sort of early release of gcloud so as of writing this, you'll want to remove the `preview` keyword from the commands above.